# Optimize laravel project with extracting methods

Tags: php, laravel, optimization, laravel-5.1

I am working on a ongoing laravel project which uses laravel 5.1. There is a process that takes over 8 seconds. within that process, there is a method that has almost 250 lines of code.In optimization perspective, if I extracted that code into several methods, will it be faster than usual or will it take much time?

Comment: Why don't you explain your long running function so we can answer in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking a big function into multiple small functions is not going to be faster instead it will become slower because of multiple function calls.

I would recommend to change your approach, use queues for async processes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP there are usually a few things you can do to speed up code:

Use references where possible.

By default, whenever you call a function with parameters, a copy of the variables is made. If a function that takes arrays or strings as parameters is called frequently, this can be very expensive. So instead of doing things like:

```
function f($array) {
```

Use:

```
function f(&$array) {
```

This implies any modification to `$array` will affect the original array too, so it should be used only in situations where either `$array` isn't modified or you don't care that it is modified.

The same is good for `foreach` loops. Just make sure to `unset()` the variable after the loop is done to avoid problems.

```
foreach ($set as &$element) { ... }
unset($element);
```

Another trick is to previously allocate buffers instead of letting them expand automatically. For example, instead of:

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 10000000];
$inverted = [];
foreach ($numbers as $num) { $inverted[] = 1 / $num; }
```

You make sure `$inverted` already has the size required to fit all the elements:

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 10000000];
$inverted = array_fill(0, count($numbers), 0);
foreach ($numbers as $i => $num) { $inverted[$i] = 1 / $num; }
```

Likewise, avoid resizing strings and arrays whenever possible. Work with indexes etc.

Regular expressions, while convenient, are the enemy of performance. Avoid using them for simple tasks.

And all that of course considering the problem is with the PHP code. Maybe it isn't. If you are using a database, you might want to reassess how you perform your SQL queries. The way you structure them can impact performance severely.